# Linux Debian: Python VENV

Tags: python, debian, python-venv

I'm new to Python / Debian and I'm trying to create a virtual environment.
I'm trying to create it with this command:
Linux Debian
python 2.7.16

rm -rf venv
python -m venv ./venv

but it gives me the following error:

/usr/bin/python: No module named venv

any ideas? why does it fail?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: `venv` is not a valid Python 2 library; you want `python3` for this, but in addition, Debian specifically excludes it from the base `python3` package; you need to `apt-get install python3-venv` to install it.